# when I click the view button, it shows invalid syntax (<string>, line 1) and I cannot watch the Variable value

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCCct.png)

I am debugging and I would like to view detailed information on the values of variables .

When I click the view button, it shows invalid syntax (, line 1) and I cannot watch the Variable value.

What I should to do for displaying normally ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.